# How to set frame rate on CCAnimation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have 5 sprite frames and i made them into an animation with a delay of 0.05 seconds between each frame. I then used CCAnimate to turn it into an action then ran it on a sprite.

```
CCAnimation *animation = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animationArray delay:0.05];
CCAnimate *animate = [CCAnimate actionWithDuration:10.0 animation:animation restoreOriginalFrame:YES];
[sprite runAction:animate];
```

The issue is that the frames have a delay of 2 seconds rather than 0.05. Is it possible to loop the animation with a frame ever 0.05 seconds for a duration of 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

1. make sure that the first argument to `CCAnimate actionWithDuration` matches the product of your delay` by the number of frames you have;
2. use `CCRepeat` to repeat in a loop your basic animation:

   ```
   CCRepeat* repeat = [CCRepeat actionWithAction:animate times:5];
   [sprite runAction:repeat];
   ```